# My 'if' statement is not changing my 'while' loop to False

Tags: python

I am working through a course where this has come up a few times now, and I've not been able to get it right.

**Edit: I have solved this now. I used a while loop, "while bidding:", then within that while loop I was able to create an 'if' statement to impact the 'bidding' variable. A function was the wrong idea for this code. **

I am creating a variable that = True early on in the code, then while it is True, running a function. Within that function is an 'if' statement that should be changing the variable to False, stopping the function, but it doesn't. I think I must have the code in the wrong order or maybe the wrong indentation.

Here is the relevant code.

```
bidding = True

bidder = input("What is your name?: ")
bid_amount = int(input("What's your bid?: $"))
more_bidders = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'. \n").lower

def add_to_dict(bidder_name, dollar_amount, anyone_else):
  bidder_dict[bidder_name] = dollar_amount
  if anyone_else == "no":
    bidding = False

while bidding:
  add_to_dict(bidder_name = bidder, dollar_amount = bid_amount, anyone_else = more_bidders)
```

I run the code fine, I type "no" when it asks if there's any more bidders, and it just pauses because it thinks "bidding" is still True. So my 'if' statement isn't doing what I need it to, but I don't know why.

Comment: `bidding` inside the function is not the same as `bidding` used in the while loop. You technically would want `global bidding` inside the function, however, there are better ways to do this without using `global`.

Comment: You can return a `bool` value from the function and use that as a check on the while loop.

Comment: @Dair you are correct. What are these better ways you mentioned? Quite new to all this

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your code much, you can use `global`:

```
def add_to_dict(bidder_name, dollar_amount, anyone_else):
  global bidding

  bidder_dict[bidder_name] = dollar_amount
  if anyone_else == "no":
    bidding = False

while bidding:
  add_to_dict(bidder_name = bidder, dollar_amount = bid_amount, anyone_else = more_bidders)
```

A better solution would be to return `bidding` from `add_to_dict()`:

```
def add_to_dict(bidder_name, dollar_amount, anyone_else):
  bidder_dict[bidder_name] = dollar_amount
  if anyone_else == "no":
    return False

  return True


while bidding:
  bidding = add_to_dict(bidder_name = bidder, dollar_amount = bid_amount, anyone_else = more_bidders)
```

Comment: You don't even need the variable: `while add_to_dict(...): pass`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is coming from the comparison in the if statement. You are seeing if the string in anyone_else is equal to "no" but you have the variable more_bidders taking in the string "yes" or "no. So I recommend either change anyone_else to more_bidders or initialize anyone_else with more_bidders before the if statement.

Comment: Even if the comparison is correct, the function sets a *local* variable, not the one used by the `while` loop.

Comment: I believe Chepner is correct. My code highlights two instances of 'bidding' but not the one inside the function when I click on the word 'bidding' outside the code. That sort of makes sense to me, I'm just not sure how to fix it. Quite new to Python, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in this way:

```
bidding = True
bidder_dict = {}
bidder = ""
bid_amount = 0
more_bidders = "yes"
def add_to_dict():
  bidder = input("What is your name?: ")
  bid_amount = int(input("What's your bid?: $"))
  more_bidders = str(input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'. \n"))
  bidder_dict[bidder] = bid_amount
  print(more_bidders)
  if more_bidders == "no":
    return False
  else:
    return True

while bidding:
  if add_to_dict():
      print("OK")
  else:
      print("Terminou")
      break
  
print(bidder_dict)
```